# How do you give a pattern to a shadow?

Tags: html, css

How do you give a pattern to a box shadow, like the dot pattern in the image?

[image]

EDIT: The screenshot is from https://fdisk.space. Going through the code this is what I've gotten so far. IIRC, bg_shadow is the image of a dot which is multiplied to get the pattern. Applying this to an element of the class "square" doesn't give the pattern though, what's the error in the code?

Also, is there some way to pull off the same effect without using a data URL?

```css
:root {
  --bg_shadow: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAYAAABytg0kAAAAD0lEQVQImWNgYGD4z4AMAA4EAQAvGW0PAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
}

.square {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.shadow {
  position: relative;
}

.shadow:after {
  background: var(--bg_shadow);
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 7px;
  top: 8px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.shadowPlus4:after {
  height: calc(100% + 3.1px);
  width: calc(100% + 3.1px);
}
```

```html
<div class="square shadow shadowPlus4"></div>
```

Comment: why you think it's a shadow? consider it as a border and you can easily do it using border-image

Comment: you don't , thats not part of the specification.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code you've used to get as far as you can, and add any research you've done into the solution.

Comment: I've changed the image for better understanding. The CSS should describe a shadow and will be used for multiple elements, so I can't use an image. I'm new to web dev so please excuse any wrong terms used

Comment: you can try the old way (before box-shadow ) and use another container and a background : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GRNmRjZ

Comment: Thank you @G-Cyrillus. Will look into it